# Why my golang log not write into analyze.log?

Tags: function, go, logging

```
    import (
        "log"
        "os"
    ) 
// main function
    func main() {
         infoLog := makeLogger()
         infoLog.Printf("write to file analyze.log ")
    }
// return logger function
    func makeLogger() (i *log.Logger) {
        infologFile, err := os.OpenFile("analyze.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666) // this seems not work it do create the file ,but no log write into it, why?
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer infologFile.Close() 
        infoLog := log.New(infologFile, "[INFO]: ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile|log.Lmsgprefix)
        return infoLog
    }
```

The program  do create the  file analyze.log ,but no log write into it, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is closed via `defer` in `makeLogger` function. The line

```golang
infoLog.Printf("write to file analyze.log ")
```

will try to write to a closed file.

---

Instead the file should be closed via defer in the main function. For example:

```golang
    import (
        "log"
        "os"
    ) 

    func main() {
         infoLog, closeLog := makeLogger()
         defer closeLog() 

         infoLog.Printf("write to file analyze.log ")
    }

    func makeLogger() (i *log.Logger, close func() error) {
        infologFile, err := os.OpenFile("analyze.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666) // this seems not work it do create the file ,but no log write into it, why?
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        infoLog := log.New(infologFile, "[INFO]: ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile|log.Lmsgprefix)
        return infoLog, infologFile.Close
    }
```

Note: In log files you'd usually want to `os.O_APPEND` otherwise the file will be overwritten every time the app starts again.

Comment: Perfectly explained and resolution!

Answer (score -2):

Not tested, but I think you miss the os.O_APPEND

```golang
// return logger function
func makeLogger() *log.Logger {
    infologFile, err := os.OpenFile("analyze.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

otherwise you only create a file, but dont write anything to it

Comment: That`s not the problem,i remove  os.O_APPEND  to ensure it`s always flush the old log when the program restart